# Does LSTM-Keras take into account dependencies between time series?

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm

I have:

- Multiple time series as INPUT
- Forecast time series point in OUTPUT

How can be sure that model predict data by using dependencies between all time series in input?

**Edit 1**
My current model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_nodes, input_dim=num_features, input_length=window, consume_less="mem"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_features, activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

Comment: Can you add your current model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default LSTM layer in keras (and any other type of recurrent layer) is not stateful, and hence the states are reset every time a new input is fed into the network. Your code uses this default version. If you want, you can make it stateful by specifying `stateful=True` inside the LSTM layer, and then the states will not be reset. You can read more about the relevant syntax [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), and [this blog post](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) provides more information regarding the stateful mode.

Here is an example of the corresponding syntax, taken from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/):

```
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))
# create and fit the LSTM network
batch_size = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
for i in range(100):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX, batch_size=batch_size)
model.reset_states()
testPredict = model.predict(testX, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: In this case, batch_size it's equal to 1 but I don't think that fit to my problem. What do you think?

Comment: It is just easier to take batch size=1 (and you can do that as well, it'll just make the code to run slower). Otherwise, you'll have to carefully rearrange the data. This is due to the following sentence from the second link provided in my answer, "With the stateful model, all the states are propagated to the next batch. It means that the state of the sample located at index i X_i  will be used in the computation of the sample X_i+bs   in the next batch, where bs 
is the batch size (no shuffling)"